# shakapacker: Webpacker can't find subdir/image.png in manifest.json

Tags: ruby-on-rails, webpack, webpacker, shakapacker

I am trying to upgrade my app to Rails 7 and decided to upgrade shakapacker (aka webpacker 6).

I like to have images in app/javascript/images organized into subdirectories but for some reason this whole structure gets flattened by skakapacker/webpack.

So `<%= image_pack_tag "subdir/image.png" %>` raises an error but `<%= image_pack_tag "image.png" %>` works.

My only clue so far is the doc for [webpack-asset-manifest](https://github.com/webdeveric/webpack-assets-manifest) which says: `will generate a JSON file that matches the original filename with the hashed version` - emphasis on the filename. This might be a change since webpack days?

Also the manifest.json looks different now with shakapacker.
Webpcker used to be:

```
"media/images/favicons/a/favicon.ico": "/packs/media/images/favicons/a/favicon-bdfbf38fd01fae2abb3e1ac7de9c3a12.ico",
```

now with shakapacker:

```
"static/image.png": "/packs-test/static/image-bd51daf42131d4298622.png"
```

You can find the minimal rails app replicating this on my [github](https://github.com/honzasterba/packer-test).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was indeed a bug in webpacker6/shakapacker.

https://github.com/shakacode/shakapacker/issues/44

Answer (score 1):

In your packs/application.js you should have this

```
const images = require.context('../images', true)
```

true is including all subdirectories

check out this https://webpack.js.org/guides/dependency-management/

Comment: I do have that. Added link to testing repo